# Can we install sitecore packages using Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to install sitecore items packages in sitecore using Windows Powershell? The sitecore packages are created using "Package Designer" in sitecore. If possible, please help me with the powershell command.
Please note here that we do not intend to use SPE module. Only Windows Powershell needs to be used.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588549/install-sitecore-update-packages-with-powershell

Comment: I'm not aware of any ootb capabilities that expose this functionality outside a running instance of Sitecore.

Comment: may I know why you don't wanna go with Sitecore powershell extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can install an admin script that installs a package by calling an URL from Windows PowerShell. Be aware, it is today not very common to do that. The code is easy and adjustable so that's a plus.

There are some script available to do that, the do only the install part, not the upload, you can upload the package with other tools.

See InstallZipPackage.aspx on:
https://github.com/jbluemink/Sitecore-Admin-Scripts-for-Development-and-Deploying or
https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Deployment-Helpers

An other options that may fit if you run on Azure, is converting the Package to a Web Deploy Packages
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/24/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/web-deploy-packages-for-a-module.html